# docker compose with profiles

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I fail to understand how profiles work in docker compose.

So, I'm having two services defined in the `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  db:
    (...)
    profiles:
      - default
      - db
  app:
    (...)
    profiles:
      - default
```

When I run `docker compose --profile db` it indicates correctly to run only the `db` service [`Running 1/0`]. However, the `app` is also "attached".

[image: docker compose with profiles]

How can I prevent the `app` being attached?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: Did you shut down the compose stack beforehand (with `docker compose down`)? I.e. were all containers really stopped?

Comment: Yes, I `down`ed the containers.